# Equivalency of RLIKE/REGEXP and LIKE - matching whole string vs. arbitrary substring

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like, rlike, regexp-like

I have two queries.

```
SELECT count(AlbumID)
  FROM album
  WHERE albumname like '%[%]';
```

Result: 15733

```
SELECT count(AlbumName)
  FROM album
  WHERE AlbumName RLIKE '.*\\[.*\\]';
```

Result: 15740

So as you can see like returns 7 elements less than rlike. I have two questions why is that? Are the statements not the same? And if I am looking for names that contain lets say `Result: Artist - Song [Live]` or `Result: Artist- Song [Gold CD, Excplicit Lyrics]` what would query would return the correct result?

Comment: What does `SELECT count(AlbumID)
FROM album
WHERE AlbumName RLIKE '.*\\[.*\\]';` show? Are there any `AlbumID` which are `null`? ==> `select count(*) from album where AlbumID is null` What's result of `select count(*) from album where albumname like '%[%]';`

Comment: @EagleRainbow  the first query got the same number 15740. The second query got the result 0 so there are no albums like that. And the 3rd query got the same result as the AlbumID count which is 15733. So the different select did not affect the result. Would you know why that is?

Comment: Perform `SELECT AlbumName FROM album WHERE ... rlike ... AND ... NOT like ...` to see the 7 mystery rows.  What is in common among them?  Then answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact equivalency of

```
LIKE '%[%]'
```

is

```
REGEXP '^.*\\[.*\\]$'
```

(note that RLIKE is just a [mSQL'ish synonym of REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)). In short that means that `LIKE` always matches the whole string, whilst `REGEXP` and `RLIKE` may match any substring.

That is why I would assume that there are apparently seven AlbumNames around like

```
MyName[abc]plus
```

or

```
MyName [abc]!
```

You may try to determine these seven records by

```
SELECT AlbumName FROM album 
WHERE AlbumName RLIKE '.*\\[.*\\]' AND AlbumName NOT RLIKE '^.*\\[.*\\]$';
```